# Java Selection Sort Exchange not working as desired

Tags: java, sorting, selection

***My task: Create a selection sort that will work with strings and integers.***

Hello, I was wondering if someone could tell me why my list will not sort, whatever list I input, just gets spit back out in the same order. I am new to StackOverflow and JavaProgramming in general. I am sorry for any novice mistakes I am currently making.

```
public class selectionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sort(args);
        printArray(args);
    }

    public static void sort(String[] array) {
        int outer = 0;
        while (outer < array.length - 1) {
            outer++;
            int minimumIndex = outer;
            int inner = outer + 1;
            while (inner < array.length) {
                inner++;
                if (inner < minimumIndex) {
                    minimumIndex = inner;
                }
            }
            //exchange
            String temp = array[minimumIndex];
            array[minimumIndex] = array[outer];
            array[outer] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(String[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the expected sorted results?

Comment: Hi Hong, let's say I input : 4 6 3 2, my output is 4 6 3 2, my desired output would be, 2 3 4 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing the value of Strings in array:

> ```
>             if (inner < minimumIndex) {
>                 minimumIndex = inner;
>             }
> ```

Maybe you need this(If you want to sort the Strings by the `int` value of String):

```
            if (Integer.parseInt(array[inner]) < Integer.parseInt(array[minimumIndex])) {
                minimumIndex = inner;
            }
```

Tested code:

```
public static void sort(String[] array) {
    int outer = 0;
    while (outer < array.length - 1) {
        int minimumIndex = outer;
        int inner = outer + 1;
        while (inner < array.length) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(array[inner]) < Integer.parseInt(array[minimumIndex])) {
                minimumIndex = inner;
            }
            inner++;
        }
        //exchange
        String temp = array[minimumIndex];
        array[minimumIndex] = array[outer];
        array[outer] = temp;
        outer++;
    }
}
```

If you want to sort it by String:

```
            if (array[inner].compareTo(array[minimumIndex]) < 0) {
                minimumIndex = inner;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, while I am sure this will produce my desired output, I have not learned how to use .parseInt yet, and therefore will not be accepted, while I understand this is a perfectly fine solution to my problem and I thank you for that, I will have to continue searching, is there anything I can do with .compareTo instead? Once again, thank you for your support.

Comment: Sure you can also use `.compareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Java Array has a built in operation called sort(). Which will do the sorting for you.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

So your code can be rewritten as,

```
//import Arrays module
import java.util.Arrays;

public class selectionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sort(args);
        printArray(args);
    }

    public static void sort(String[] array) {
        //sort your array
        Arrays.sort(array);
    }
    public static void printArray(String[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on Arrays, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: This looks great too, but I think I actually have to do the sorting myself, I am trying to create something exactly like this video that will work with any arguments I type into the command prompt, not a preset array. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEqnBc3kZNI

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do the sorting yourself, you can do this with a integer array,

```
public class sorting {

    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{

        for(int s = 0; s <= arg.length - 1; s++){

            for(int k = 0; k <= arg.length - 2; k++){

                if(j[k] > j[k+1]){ //comparing array values

                    int temp = 0;
                    temp = j[k]; //storing value of array in temp variable 
                    j[k] = j[k+1]; //swaping values
                    j[k+1] = temp; //now storing temp value in array
                }    //end if block             
            }  // end inner loop    
        }
        //end outer loop
        for(int s = 0; s <= j.length - 1; s++){
            System.out.println(j[s]); //retrieving values of array in ascending order 
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
// 1. Find the minimum value in the list.
// 2. Swap the minimum value with the value in the first position.
// 3. move the insertion point for the minimum along one.
// 4. Repeat the steps above for the remainder of the list

public static void yoursort(String[]array) {
    int currentIndex = 0;
    while(currentIndex < array.length-1) {
        currentIndex++;
        int indexOfMinimum = currentIndex;           
        int candidateMinIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        while(candidateMinIndex < array.length) {
            candidateMinIndex++;
            if(candidateMinIndex < indexOfMinimum) {
                indexOfMinimum = candidateMinIndex;
            }
        }
        swap(array, currentIndex, indexOfMinimum);
    }
}

public static void mysort(String[]array) {
    int currentIndex = 0;
    while(currentIndex < array.length-1) { // dont need to do the last one
        int indexOfMinimum = findIndexOfMinimum(array, currentIndex);
        swap(array, currentIndex, indexOfMinimum);
        currentIndex++;
    }
}

protected static int findIndexOfMinimum(String[] array, int startIndex) {
    int indexOfMinimum = startIndex; // start off asumming next is minimum
    int candidateIndex = startIndex + 1; // can shift candidate along to second element.
    while(candidateIndex < array.length) {  
        // compare candidate and minimum
        if ( array[candidateIndex].compareTo(array[indexOfMinimum]) < 0 ) {
            // ie array[candidateIndex] before/smaller array[indexOfMinimum] 
            indexOfMinimum = candidateIndex;        
        }                    
        candidateIndex++;
    }
    return indexOfMinimum;
}

protected static void swap(String[] array, int toIndex, int fromIndex) {
    if ( toIndex == fromIndex ) {
        // fast return if swapping with self.
        return;
    }

    String temp = array[toIndex];
    array[toIndex] = array[fromIndex];
    array[toIndex] = temp;
}
```

Note you are not actually comparing the elements in your array just their indexes. I think you will find things a lot simpler if you extract code out into methods.

Comment: Thank you, while I do not understand what some parts of your code mean, your comments were very useful to help me understand how selection sort works. I will come back to this when I understand it fully.

Comment: first... i moved the swap (exchange) to a seperate method, and added a fast return if your trying to swap with yourself. then i renamed the variables in yoursort... it highlights that your not comparing values, and doing some funky incrementing. so then i wrote mysort to demonstrate what i think you were actually after.